# How to hide the cursor in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm running JDK 1.8.0_65 with OpenJFX 8u40. JavaFX has `javafx.scene.Scene.setCursor`, analogous to a method of the same name in Swing, but unlike the later, setting it to `Cursor.NONE` only hides it until the cursor is moved, and then it goes back to `Cursor.DEFAULT` permanently. I also tried to set a transparent image as a cursor but I got the same result. Is this feature broken in OpenJFX?

Comment: [There is workaround for the bug i posted it in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794346/raspberry-pi-cant-hide-mouse-cursor-in-javafx-application/42966191#42966191)

Answer (score 1):

For me this perfectly work :

```
public class cursor extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    HBox root = new HBox();
    Scene scene =   new Scene(root);

    scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);       


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(300);
    primaryStage.setHeight(300);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Does this also work if you have text fields anywhere in this scene?