# How to hide the mouse pointer in javafx

Tags: javafx, mouse-cursor

I want to make a program with fullscreen，so I don't want a mouse pointer. I used `Mouse.hide()` in Flex before, I can not find related information in JavaFX. How can I hide the mouse pointer?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530216/how-to-hide-the-cursor-in-javafx ? Note: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi can't hide mouse cursor in JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794346/raspberry-pi-cant-hide-mouse-cursor-in-javafx-application)